# Programming using pyclutter

Tags: python, opengl, cogl

I am new to [clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/) (and [pyclutter](http://wiki.clutter-project.org/wiki/PyClutter)).

I have been trying to use pyclutter. I haven't found any good tutorial for it so far. I mean nothing that really explains properly. I saw a couple of example programs but when I tried to use pyclutter I didn't get any good results.

The commands are available but their proper use is what is causing a problem. I tried to render a line using pyclutter but haven't even been able to do that.

My code:

```
import clutter
from clutter import cogl

stage = clutter.Stage()
stage.set_size(400, 400)

label = clutter.Text()
label.set_text("line")
stage.add(label)

clutter.cogl.set_source_color4ub (255,0,0,255)
clutter.cogl.path_line(100,100,200,200)
clutter.cogl.path_stroke()

stage.show_all()
stage.connect("destroy",clutter.main_quit)
clutter.main()
```

It's possible that my mistakes are really stupid, but I'd be really grateful if anyone could point me to a good tutorial where i can learn clutter (pyclutter) from and help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [programming using pyclutter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985686/programming-using-pyclutter)

Answer (score 2):

What about this one: http://www.tuxradar.com/content/clutter-beginners-tutorial. It looks pretty decent.

Comment: That's not even python